# Jquery Mobile get Page Animation(transition) with data-ajax=false.. is it possible?(workaround)

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, jquery-mobile, transition

I have a Form with Post method and `data-ajax="false"`
But I would like to have the Page animation when I submit the Form.

Is it possible? maybe with a workaround?

Comment: how is `data-ajax="false"` related to the page animation.. :o and what kind of animation you are talking about???

Comment: jquery mobile has animation when u switch the page

Comment: **[This link](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0/docs/pages/page-transitions.html)** is what you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible as per the below statement given:

> **Linking without Ajax**
>
> Links that point to other domains or that have `rel="external"`,
>   `data-ajax="false"` or target attributes will not be loaded with Ajax.
>   Instead, **these links will cause a full page refresh with no animated
>   transition**. Both attributes (`rel="external"` and `data-ajax="false"`)
>   have the same effect, but a different semantic meaning: `rel="external"`
>   should be used when linking to another site or domain, while
>   `data-ajax="false"` is useful for simply opting a page within your
>   domain from being loaded via Ajax. **Because of security restrictions,
>   the framework always opts links to external domains out of the Ajax
>   behavior**.
>
> **Note:** When building a jQuery Mobile application where the Ajax
>   navigation system is disabled globally or frequently disabled on
>   individual links, we recommend disabling the `$.mobile.pushStateEnabled`
>   global configuration option to avoid inconsistent navigation behavior
>   in some browsers.

**[SOURCE](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0/docs/pages/page-links.html)**

Comment: When they have mentioned in their docs itself I don't think there might be a way.. but some jQuery-mobile pro might do it but in his own way.. :)

Comment: where i can find this creatures ;)) joke ^^... i will try to find a Forum for these pros ^^

Comment: Lol. Good luck with your try.. :)